# import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Tags: python, xml

I have the XML:

```py
    response = """<response status="success">
    <result>
        <licenses>
            <entry>
                <feature>Threat Prevention</feature>
                <description>Threat Prevention</description>
                <serial>123</serial>
                <issued>May 03, 2022</issued>
                <expires>May 25, 2023</expires>
                <expired>no</expired>
                <authcode>2222222</authcode>
            </entry>

            <entry>
                <feature>PAN-DB URL Filtering</feature>
                <description>Palo Alto Networks URL Filtering License</description>
                <serial>34143215</serial>
                <issued>May 05, 2022</issued>
                <expires>May 25, 2023</expires>
                <expired>no</expired>
                <authcode/>
            </entry>
            
            <entry>
                <feature>Logging Service</feature>
                <description>Device Logging Service</description>
                <serial>145145145</serial>
                <issued>December 18, 2018</issued>
                <expires>February 12, 2019</expires>
                <expired>yes</expired>
                <custom>
                    <_Log_Storage_TB>5</_Log_Storage_TB>
                </custom>
                <authcode/>
            </entry>
        </licenses>
    </result>
</response>
```

I need to get all values in `<entry>` , but i need a dynamic query, because if the tool add a new tags into entry, e need get too.

I`m try to get the data in differents models..

```py
root = ET.fromstring(response)
for elem in root.iter():
    print(elem.text)
```

But doesn't work.  How can I get this data only ..

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "But doesn't work" does not explain what the actual problem is. And the question title does not help either. The title should be a short summary of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here something that can help you

```py
for entry in root.findall("result/licenses/entry"):
    for elem in entry.iter():
        print(f"Element tag {elem.tag} Value : {elem.text}")
```

Here the output that i got

```
Element tag entry Value :

Element tag feature Value : Threat Prevention
Element tag description Value : Threat Prevention
Element tag serial Value : 123
Element tag issued Value : May 03, 2022
Element tag expires Value : May 25, 2023
Element tag expired Value : no
Element tag authcode Value : 2222222
Element tag entry Value :

Element tag feature Value : PAN-DB URL Filtering
Element tag description Value : Palo Alto Networks URL Filtering License
Element tag serial Value : 34143215
Element tag issued Value : May 05, 2022
Element tag expires Value : May 25, 2023
Element tag expired Value : no
Element tag authcode Value : None
Element tag entry Value :

Element tag feature Value : Logging Service
Element tag description Value : Device Logging Service
Element tag serial Value : 145145145
Element tag issued Value : December 18, 2018
Element tag expires Value : February 12, 2019
Element tag expired Value : yes
Element tag custom Value :

Element tag _Log_Storage_TB Value : 5
Element tag authcode Value : None
```

Comment: You should mark it as solved ..